# Delegate Method failing to call when tested with If statement, but calls correctly without If statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, uikit

I have this if statement checking if my delegate has implemented a given method:

```
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:)])
{
        [self.delegate didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:self withNotification:notification];

}
```

However my code is not getting executed within the If statement. I have other delegate calls working between these objects **and** if I remove the if statement and just call

```
[self.delegate didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:self withNotification:notification];
```

on its own it works!

My delegate does implement correctly:

```
- (void)didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:(NotificationDialogView *)dialogView withNotification:(NotificationContext *)setNotification{
    NSLog(@"Notification is: %@", setNotification);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the method is wrong. It should be `didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:withNotification:`.

Try this:

```
 if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:withNotification:)]) {
    [self.delegate didFinishSettingNotificationOnDialog:self withNotification:notification];
}
```